# Map/Set Implementation for working with IE 8

Tags: javascript, dictionary, internet-explorer-8, set, polyfills

I would like to use a map / set in Javascript like it's currently available in FireFox 31.

```
var myMap = new Map();
```

Also I would like to be able to use this in IE 8 / 9 / 10 so I need a working polyfill. No polyfill that I have found (like collectionjs.com) work with IE 8.

Does anybody know a good Map implementation that works with IE 8?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I've found something here. Seems to be promising

http://www.timdown.co.uk/jshashtable/index.html#api